# Fastest way to duplicate encrypted hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, encryption, rsync

I used hard drive duplicator to do the sector-by-sector duplication of hard drives. I think it took about 5 hours.

Pros:

- easy
- unattended, computer-free operation

Cons:

- hard drive size restriction (src < dest)
- more writes, thus wearing out the hard drive more

This is comparable to the time (~4 hours) it takes for me to sync via robocopy or rsync after decrypting the drives, because I do have many small files. The hard drives were connected via USB 3.0.

Pros:

- Flexibility of using any hard drives
- Less writes

Cons:

- need to decrypt first
- a computer needs to be dedicated duration of the operation

I would like to know if there is a significantly better or faster method out there.

The ideal solution, I think is if the duplicator had the ability to do a check-sum before committing to write so that it minimize the write time, because most majority of the files will not change between the backups.

Comment: You don't indicate what OS you are using, so I can't determine, which of the duplicate questions this is a duplicate of.

Comment: To me it is a bit unclear what you want to achieve. Duplication and regular backup are two different things, and you would usually go about them differently. For example, sector-wise copying is a bad idea for backups, because you usually want to retain multiple backup sets. Rsync does the "copy only if changed" thing you mention. Even better, rsnapshot retains multiple versions of the backup in a convenient hard-linked format.

Comment: @Ramhound I use Windows and Linux, This question should be OS agnostic.

Comment: @Fritz I do multiple versioning for system backup via a proprietary software. The rest of the files I don't need versioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sector by sector duplicator has no idea of files or the file system so there is no way for it to compare data and minimize write time like you said (plus it's not a computer). Now decrypting (and then syncing) can actually take longer depending on how it's encrypted and the amount of data because you're basically doing a decryption calculation that can be CPU intensive, and a copy just like a duplicator except in this case it doesn't have to copy the blank space, and you can do a file comparison. That's with a full disk encryption method. With something like Windows' Bitlocker or OS X's FileVault, the decryption is done on the fly when using it so you don't really need to do the decryption step explicitly - you just plug it into another Windows or OS X computer and authenticate.

We use duplicators here at work, but that's because it allows us to get more done with less computers, and we have lots of large disks at hand. If your main purpose is backup, I'd still do it the normal way, without removing the disk, and just plugging the backup disk into the computer with USB or whatever like you did. (Then check the backup to make sure you did what you expected to do.)